# nosetests not running all the tests in a file

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, decorator, fixtures

i run

`nosetests -v --nocapture --nologcapture tests/reward/test_stuff.py`

i get

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------

    Ran 7 tests in 0.005s

    OK
```

the tests without decorators run fine, however i have some fixture tests setup liike so which aren't running in the above command:

```
@use_fixtures(fixtures.ap_user_data, fixtures.ap_like_data, fixtures.other_reward_data)
def test_settings_are_respected(data):
    """
    Tests setting takes effect
    """
    res = func()
    assert len(res) > 0
```

the decorator is:

```
def use_fixtures(*fixtures):
    """
    Decorator for tests, abstracts the build-up required when using fixtures 
    """
    def real_use_fixtures(func):
        def use_fixtures_inner(*args, **kwargs):
            env = {}
            for cls in fixtures:
                name = cls.__name__
                table = name[:-5] #curtails _data
                env[table] = get_orm_class(table)

            fixture = SQLAlchemyFixture(env=env, engine=engine, style=TrimmedNameStyle(suffix="_data"))
            return fixture.with_data(*fixtures)(func)()
        return use_fixtures_inner
    return real_use_fixtures
```

is my use of decorators stopping nosetests from running my tests ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your decorator is causing nose to miss tests, but what if you take a test with a decorator, and remove the decorator long enough to see if it's still missed?

Comment: good call, i removed the decorator and it caught the test but failed because some of the data expected by the preloader was missing. now i can safely say it is the decorator, but i'm unsure why.

Comment: It might be that with the decorator applied, nosetests sees the name of the test differently, and therefore thinks it is not a test and ignores it. You might want to try writing your decorator with `functools.wraps`, which helps preserve original function's docstring etc. properties.